# join of value lists in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to join two value lists in postgres.
I tried the following but it does not work;

```
select a.*,b.* from (values('a'),('b')) as a join (values('1'),('2'),('3')) as b ;
```

What should I write instead ;
The result should be a table of 6 values.

Comment: You cannot inner join 2 lists because there isn't any matching key. Do you want to cross join values ?

Comment: cross join, conditions just limit the output set

Comment: as you indicated, it works with cross join but not with join. In order to work with join I have to put an on clause as e.g. "on true". From what I knew until now a "join" without condition gives a cross join and it is not necessary to indicate "cross join".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to cross join values so that you will get 6 values.

```
select
    a.*,
    b.* 
  from (values('a'),('b')) as a (a),  
  (values('1'),('2'),('3')) as b (b);
```

```
a | b
--|--
a | 1
b | 1
a | 2
b | 2
a | 3
b | 3
```

Here is another statement with same result (with join clause)

```
select
    a.*,
    b.* 
  from (values('a'),('b')) as a (a)
  cross join (values('1'),('2'),('3')) as b (b);
```

Comment: What the "(a)" after the "a" means ;

Comment: it's column alias. it is for naming the output column

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough (from what I knew until now) it works only with the two forms bellow:

```
    select a.*,b.* from 
(values('a'),('b')) as a cross join (values('1'),('2'),('3')) as b ;
    
    select a.*,b.* from 
(values('a'),('b')) as a join (values('1'),('2'),('3')) as b on true;
```